# Clear cache for specific site on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, cache

How do you clear the cache for a specific site on Chrome for Android?

I've already tried going to the site's settings and pressing the "Clear & Reset" button, but the site's cache still hasn't been cleared (the JavaScript file that's loaded is still the old version).

So how do I do this properly?

Answer (score 11):

From the overflow (3 dots menu)

Settings → Site settings → tap `All sites`   → choose your site 
 →`clear and reset`

[From Chrome help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392709?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

> Cached images and files: Chrome remembers parts of pages to help them open faster during your next visit. Text and images from pages you've visited in Chrome are removed.

You will also lose browsing history, cookies and site data

Comment: I said in my question that I already tried that, but that the JavaScript that's loaded is still the old version.

Comment: Oh.. sorry. Missed seeing that. Wondering if uninstalling and reinstalling will help after saving your bookmarks

Answer (score 0):

I use this decision (but it applies to all sites): Settings -> Privacy -> Clear browsing data. Then chose time range -> Clear data

Answer (score 0):

The option that worked for me was:

1. Go to Settings → Privacy and security → Clear browsing data
2. Check "Cached images and files".
3. Optionally select a time range if you know when the cache was created.
4. Click on "Clear data". You are then able to select your specific site. This step is made easier by the previous step because then the list will be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Under the overflow menu, click the "i" in a circle, and then "Cookies." You can then click the trash can to clear all data for just the site (Chrome calls it all "cookies").